# Setting selected entry using helper.options?

Tags: templates, scala, playframework

Im am using Play 2.0.4 and

```
helper.options(myitems)
```

in my template (inside of a helper.select)

In this case, how can I define the default selected entry, which shall be one entry out of `myitems`? Thanks for any hint!

**A little bit more about my case:**

Imagine a news archive, showing all news titles. This news archive uses pagination, pagination uses GET to pass the next/previous page number.

The play framework however will only correctly select the currently selected "select" item (here: news category) when a POST request was used - while pagination uses GET!

Intended behaviour: While a filter is applied / a specific news category is selected, this shall always be visible to the user by preselecting the currently selected news category in the "select" form.

A "screenshot" for illustration:

[image]

So, anyone having a good idea on how to cope with this problem? Any way to tell Play manually which entry from the "select" form it shall select? '_default always adds a new entry instead of selecting one out of the given options ): Would be great, if one wouldn't have to build the complete "select" form manually.

Comment: Correctly created select field + options will mark proper item automatically, anyway your sample is to short to determine what went wrong

Comment: I was wondering about this too, guess the problem is that I am currently using GET and not POST - I am listing some entries and page numbers etc. are passed by GET, somehow it feels strange to use POST to filter them, also using POST one can't directly access filtered entries...

Comment: +1 for drawing :) Anyway, to pass the value to the view you probably first need to read it from request, right? ie `&cat=123` We now understand well what you need anyway, without look into the code it's impossible to say what's wrong

Comment: well, the wrong thing is that I am using GET and not POST, it's not special about my code ):

Comment: it IS about the code, to use the data from the request you need to fetch it somehow (for an example for filtering SQL results). The GET/POSt mischmash probably is somwhere in your code

Comment: the problem is that changing pages is a GET request and preselecting a value in a select form is only supported when using POST. So even if I send the filtering select form using POST, as soon as I change the page no entry will be preselected anymore in the filtering select form. Fetching the data is not the problem, the problem is to tell the Play framework to preselect an entry of the filtering select form based on a value that is not provided by POST but instead by a user defined value. This is a general problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try passing `'_default` option to `select` helper:

```
@import views.html.helper._

@select(form("email"), options(List("first", "third")), '_default -> "second")
```

It seems, unfortunately, the only way to figure it out is to look up the [source](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/select.scala.html).

**Update:**

Specifying `_default` property doesn't set `selected` attribute on `option` tag. It looks like the only way to preselect entry is to pass prefilled form to the template. For example, suppose you have following form:

```
case class RegInfo(email: String, color: String)

private val registrationForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "email"    → email,
    "color"    → nonEmptyText(minLength = 5, maxLength = 32)
  )(RegInfo.apply)(RegInfo.unapply)
)
```

Then in the action prefill form before passing to the view:

```
def create = Action {
  Ok(html.create(registrationForm.fill(RegInfo("user@qwe.com", "blue"))))
}
```

Then in template use helper:

```
@select(form("color"), options(List("red", "green", "blue")))
```

And value will be preselected.

Comment: Actually it's included in the play getting started documentation, but the problem with this emthod is, that the default entry is not part of the normal entries. Somehow Play seems to expect that one uses POST instead of GET, then the proper entry will be selected automatically. Problem is I am not using POST at the moment ;-)

Comment: I've updated my answer. May be it will work for you. And tell us more about your case, please.

Comment: Thank you! I added more details to my original post. Could you post your solution as Java? Or maybe you have a completely new idea, now that I added more details to my problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with the pragmatic approach:

```
<select id="myfield" name="myfield" >

    <option class="blank" value="">-- All items --</option>

    @for((key, value) <- MyModel.options) {

        @if(key == GETValuePassedToTemplate) {
            <option value="@key" selected>@value</option>   
        } else {
            <option value="@key">@value</option>                            
        }
    }

</select>
```

Still wondering if there is a better option / way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a nicer solution to it. If you call the template having the form partially bound you will achieve your goal. Here's the code for your controller:

```
Ok(views.html.myForm(myForm.bind(
             Map("fieldName1" -> "value1",
                 "fieldName2" -> "value2"))))
```

Make sure you map fieldnames to the `value`s of the `option`s you want pre-selected.

Answer (score 0):

> Still wondering if there is a better option / way to do it.

Well, if your not hell-bent on using play to solve this particular problem, you could always solve it using JavaScript and jQuery:

```
$(function () {    
    $('#yourSelect_id').val(5);
}
```

Where your select options each has values and the one option you whish to pre select has value 5.